# MVC 4/5 pluploader v2.1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

So I'm trying to get [pluploader v2.1.9](http://www.plupload.com/)  to work for MVC 4 or 5, I must be completely missing the Idea behind it because i cant find a tutorial or really anything that goes into detail with it. I've googled and searched this site and haven't found a real answer.

I'm trying to get the UI Widget to work so i have followed the directions on the site [here](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Getting-Started) and entered the code from [UI Widget](http://www.plupload.com/examples/ui) it gives me the read out saying:

> Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.

Maybe I'm just too new to MVC or missing a key item here. Any help will be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So i get  a down vote with no explanation of why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example : [MVC4 ASP.Net Example](https://pluploadmvc4demo.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This help get me started and i was able to figure out how to implement the UI Widget. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The key to the View was linking all the external files, and doing it correctly 
The View

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>UI Widget</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/js/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- production -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/js/jquery.ui.plupload /jquery.ui.plupload.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="font: 13px Verdana; background: #eee; color: #333">

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
    <div id="uploader">
        <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
    </div>
     <br />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the widget when the DOM is ready
    $(function () {
        $("#uploader").plupload({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
            //url: 'Scripts/upload.php',
            url: 'Home/Upload', 
            // User can upload no more then 20 files in one go (sets multiple_queues to false)
            max_file_count: 20,

            chunk_size: '1mb',

            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            resize: {
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                quality: 90,
                crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
            },

            filters: {
                // Maximum file size
                max_file_size: '1000mb',
                // Specify what files to browse for
                mime_types: [
                    { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
                    { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
                ]
            },

            // Rename files by clicking on their titles
            rename: true,

            // Sort files
            sortable: true,

            // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
            dragdrop: true,

            // Views to activate
            views: {
                list: true,
                thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
                active: 'thumbs'
            },

            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: 'Scripts/js/Moxie.swf',

            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: 'Scripts/js/Moxie.xap'
        });


        // Handle the case when form was submitted before uploading has finished
        $('#form').submit(function (e) {
            // Files in queue upload them first
            if ($('#uploader').plupload('getFiles').length > 0) {

                // When all files are uploaded submit form
                $('#uploader').on('complete', function () {
                    $('#form')[0].submit();
                });

                $('#uploader').plupload('start');
            } else {
                alert("You must have at least one file in the queue.");
            }
            return false; // Keep the form from submitting
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then there is the Controller, which was what i got from the Link provided from above.

HomeController

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace PluploadMVC4Demo.Controllers
 {
  public class HomeController : Controller
 {

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];
            file.SaveAs(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads/" + file.FileName);
        }
        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

}

You need to add a Folder called Uploads to the root Dir to store the files. 
so your file structure should look something like this.

[image]

The only problem now is on how to keep the current file that is being uploaded from over ridding any existing files with the same name.